# How to clone TestNG's TestResult

Tags: java, testng, clone

How can we clone one TestNG's `TestResult` to another object?

Below code couldn't create one new object of `TestResult`:

```
TestResult tmpTestResult = (TestResult) Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [constructor with parameters](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/internal/TestResult.html#TestResult(org.testng.IClass,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.testng.ITestNGMethod,%20java.lang.Throwable,%20long,%20long,%20org.testng.ITestContext)) to create new object

```
TestResult newTestResult = new TestResult(tmpTestResult.getTestClass(),
                tmpTestResult.getInstance(),
                tmpTestResult.getMethod(),
                tmpTestResult.getThrowable(),
                tmpTestResult.getStartMillis(),
                tmpTestResult.getEndMillis(),
                tmpTestResult.getTestContext());
```